# Resourses.LoadAll not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, sprite

I'm trying load in a Sprite Array Sprite, sliced in Editor using code, but sprites. Length always returns 0. A folder named "Sprites" is in Assets' folder and a sliced picture is in Sprites. Why it isn't working?

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites");
```

Comment: Sprites need to be in Resources folder, see: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sprites folder must be in the `Resources` folder. Like this:

[image]

It is also worth pointing out that your code is looking for files that are marked as `Sprite`.

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites");
```

This means that your pictures must have this format or they won't be added to the array.

[image]

Or you could just load them all as Objects like this:

```
Object[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll("Sprites");
```

Comment: I am just learning Unity, and had the same issue. I had a file in the Assets folder called: ponies.png. This code did not work:
ponySprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("ponies");
Then I created a folder called Resources under Assets and moved ponies.png and ponies.png.meta there. Then the code worked.

Comment: Of course, after I spliced the ponies.png, see https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sprite-editor

Comment: Why loading them as Object ? this is bad practice

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds When you're loading from a path, you don't know what types of assets you're going to find. You can only find Sprites, but you may also find sprites AND a material for example. Your script will fail while trying to cast a material to a sprite and you'll get an exception.